# Fibonacci Sequence in MIPS using a while loop

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm trying to write a program that allows for the user find to find out the nth fibonacci sequence. I'm new to MIPS however and I cannot seem to get it working. It's confusing the hell out of me.

```
    .data
    msg: .asciiz "Please enter a number to calculate the fibonnaci sequence for"
    equalsOne: .asciiz "The answer is 1"
    equalsTwo: .asciiz "The answer is 2"
    answer: .asciiz "The answer is "


.text
    addi $v0, $zero, 4  #Set $v0 to 4 (Print String)
    la $a0, msg         #Set memory address of msg to $a0
    syscall
    addi $v0, $zero, 5  #Set $v0 to 5 (Read Integer)
    syscall
    add $t0, $zero, $v0 #Store input integer in $t0
    beq $t0, 1, equals1 #If input integer == 1, go to equals1 
    beq $t0, 2, equals2 #If input integer == 2, go to equals2
    addi $t1, $zero, 1  #Stores 1 in register $t1
    addi $a1, $zero, 1  # $a1 = currentNumber
    addi $a2, $zero, 1  # $a2 = oldNumber

fib:    slt $t2, $a1, $t0   #While $a1 < $t0
    bne $t2, 1, exit
    add $a3, $a1, $a2   # $a3 = nextNumber = currentNumber + oldNumber
    add $a2, $a1, $zero #Set oldNumber = currentNumber
    add $a1, $a3, $zero #Set currentNumber = nextNumber
    j fib

equals1: la $a0, equalsOne
    addi $v0, $zero, 4
    syscall

equals2: la $a0, equalsTwo
    addi $v0, $zero, 4
    syscall

exit: addi $v0, $zero, 1    #Print integer
    add $a1, $a1, $zero #Print nextNumber
    syscall
```

Comment: So what actually happens when you assemble and run this code ?

Comment: So you don't even get the initial prompt "Please enter a number ..." ?

Comment: I was going to put that in after. The answer is wrong though.

Answer (score 2):

The argument for syscall 1 goes into `$a0`. So this line:

```
add $a1, $a1, $zero #Print nextNumber
```

should be changed to:

```
add $a0, $a1, $zero #Print nextNumber
```

Note that what you'll get is the *smallest fibonacci number greater than or equal to N*. If what you really wanted was the N:th fibonacci number, you'll have to change your loop exit condition so that you iterate N times, instead of until `$a1` reaches a certain value like you do now.

Answer (score -1):

here is my code for your problem and it works properly :

```
addiu $a1,$0,1

addiu $a2,$0,1

addiu $t0,$0,2

beq $a0,$a1,exit1

beq $a0,$t0,exit1

jal fibonacci

addu $s0,$0,$v0

j done

fibonacci :

    addu $a3, $a1, $a2   # $a3 = nextNumber = currentNumber + oldNumber

    addu $a2, $a1, $zero #Set oldNumber = currentNumber

    addu $a1, $a3, $zero #Set currentNumber = nextNumber

    addiu $t0,$t0,1

    bne $t0,$a0,end

    addu $v0,$0,$a3

    jr $ra

    end: 

    j fibonacci

   exit1:

        addiu $s0,$0,1

        j done

     done:
```